# Unusual numbers format in R

Tags: r

I'm working with a data matrix I received from a colleague who no longer works in our research group. The numbers are gene expression values. When I read the data.frame using R, numbers look like this: 715.583.892.852.256, 85.363.547.324.901. I don't know why they look like that. Expected numbers are: 715.5, 85.3. Can anyone explain to me why they appear like that? How can I trim the original numbers in order to obtain the desired ones?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, follow the advice on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) In addition, please, [edit] you question and copy the first line of the original input file (or part of if too long). Thank you

Comment: @Bioinf_15 are you importing the data from a csv ? In that case `,` the comma might be causing an issue not R.

Comment: This looks like what Excel does if you import data with a different convention regarding decimal separators. E.g., import data with `.` as decimal separator into an Excel version with German settings and you'll get something like this.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much. Probably it is something related to Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brute force way:

```
x <- c("715.583.892.852.256", "85.363.547.324.901")

as.numeric(
  sapply(
    strsplit(x, "\\."),
    function(x)paste(x[1], paste(x[-1], collapse = ""), sep = ".")
  )
)
```

This gives:

```
[1] 715.58389  85.36355
```

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub("(?<=\\.\\d{3})\\.", "", x, perl = TRUE))` should be more efficient. But OP probably should fix the preceding workflow.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the regex. I tried something similar, but my regex-fu wasn't up to the task!

Comment: I always have to google for look-behind syntax.